# Why are we assuming normal forces to be equal in this FBD of liquid in a container?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

[image]

In such a container, a liquid with density $\rho$ is filled to the brim. I have to find the net force exerted on the walls. Since the horizontal component cancels out, only the vertical components remain which acts upwards here. I have figured out the answer to be conclusively $$F_y=\frac{5R^3\pi\rho g}{3}$$ by taking an element and integrating. However, my teacher suggested an alternative way of calculating which doesn't make sense to me but works out anyways.

[image]

Here he extrapolated the container where the extra mass is $m_1$, mass of the initial state container is $m$ and $N$ is the normal acting on the total container with mass $m_1+m$. Hence, $N=\pi (2R)^2R\rho g$. Now,

$$m_1g+mg=N \rightarrow(\text{Eq. 1})$$
$$mg+F_y=N\rightarrow(\text{Eq. 2})$$

Hence, $$m_1g=F_y$$
which can be calculated by

$$F_y=(4\pi R^3 \rho - \frac 73 \pi R^3 \rho)g=\frac{5R^3\pi\rho g}{3}$$

My question: How is equation 2 valid when $N$ is the normal acting on the extrapolated container? $mg+F_y$ is clearly the downward force acting on the initial container. It is also clear from equation 1 which is true only if we consider $N$ to be normal on the extrapolated container with the extra mass. How are both the normals in each equation equal?

Comment: When. you say "the force exerted on the walls." does that include the force exerted on the base, and is that the force of the fluid exerted on the walls?

Comment: @ChetMiller no and yes

Answer (score 0):

In the extrapolated situation, the key point to recognize is the the external force exerted by the outside fluid on the outside of the side wall downward is exactly equal to the internal force exerted by the internal fluid on the inside of the side wall upward.  That means that at the joint between the sidewall and the base, there is no connecting force in this extrapolated situation.  Under these circumstances, Eqn. 2 is the force balance on the fluid in the container in the extrapolated situation:  $$N - F_y=mg$$